# Change image repeatedly when hovering over same element

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I have a div with an image, and just below there's the menu.  What I need is for the image to change whenever I hover over one of the menu items.  There's a total of 5 images, for now, and every time I hover over the logo I want that image to change to the next one until it reaches the end, and then start over the cycle with image no. 1.

I'm using the switch statement for the first time, and I'm probably doing it wrong because I can't get it to work.  Right now I can change from image 1 to 2 but then it stops.

The code I have is as follows:

HTML

```
<div>
    <img id="img" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="logo"><a href="">logo</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$('#logo').bind("mouseover", function(){
    var currentimage  = $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/202/302");

    switch (currentimage) {
        case 0:
            $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/205/300");
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/200/305");
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/200/300");
            break;
    }
})
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwwzW/8/), I'd appreciate if someone could take a look and point out where i'm wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var imgs = [
  'http://placekitten.com/205/300',
  'http://placekitten.com/200/305',
  'http://placekitten.com/200/300'
];

var $img = $('#img');
$('#logo').on('mouseover', function() {
  var current = imgs.indexOf($img.attr('src'));
  $img.attr('src', imgs[++current] || imgs[0]);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xwwzW/14/

Answer (score 2):

This is not how `switch` work. `switch` is like an if-else chain:

```
if ( currentimage == 0 )
    $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/205/300");
else if ( currentimage == 1 )
    $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/200/305");
else if ( currentimage == 2 )
    $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/200/300");
```

However, `currentimage` is not `0`, `1` or `2`, it's a jQuery object. When you call:

```
var currentimage  = $('#img').attr('src',"http://placekitten.com/202/302");
```

you're setting the image's `src` attribute to `"http://placekitten.com/202/302"` and then returning the image object itself. So, the `switch` statement won't enter any `case`.

So, you need to find an alternate solution. One way would be creating a `count` variable and incrementing it on each `mouseover`, and using the `swtich` on that instead:

```
var count = 0;
...
count = (count+1)%3;
switch (count) {
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/xwwzW/13/) at jsFiddle. Not the best solution, but might help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method instead of building what could end up a massive list of switch cases 

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/xwwzW/9/

```
var images=['http://placekitten.com/202/302',
            'http://placekitten.com/205/300',
            'http://placekitten.com/200/305',
            'http://placekitten.com/200/300'];
var currentimage=0;

$('#logo').on("mouseover", function(){
    //console.log(currentimage);
    $('#img').attr('src', images[currentimage]);
    currentimage++;
    if (currentimage>images.length-1) currentimage=0;
});
```